# how to use abaqus findAt command in rootAssembly object to capture edge

Tags: python, abaqus

as title mentioned, i try to capture edge from a rootAsssembly object . Before that this findAt command works well on Part object, but fail now on rootAssembly.

```
# Part object, it works well
e1 = part0801.edges.findAt(((0,300,5340),))
region = a.Set(edges = e1, name = 'Set-2')

# method of capturing edges from rootAssembly object provided by abaqus system, the edges1's coordinates (0,0,0),(0,400,0)
a = mdb.models['CompositeBeam'].rootAssembly
e1 = a.edges
edges1 = e1.getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]', ), )
a.Set(edges=edges1, name='Wire-41-Set-1')
```

I want to use findAt or other ways to replace getSequenceFromMask command to capture the edge, how i can achieve it? Thanks you very much.

Comment: would be helpful to have this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace the commands (called as changing the format) used for geometry in replay (`.rpy`) and recovery (`.rec`) file, we can make use of `JournalingOptions`. 
This option can be used as follows:

```
session.journalOptions.setValues(replayGeometry=COORDINATE,
                                 recoverGeometry=COORDINATE)
```

Here, `replayGeometry` and `recoverGeometry` arguments corresponds to replay (`.rpy`) and recovery (`.rec`) file, respectively.
And the options for these arguments are

1. COMPRESSEDINDEX - (default) uses`getSequenceFromMask()` command for geometry selection.
2. COORDINATE - uses `findAt()` command for geometry selection.
3. INDEX - uses index to select geometry (ex. edges[1]).

Above line you can paste in Command Line Interface (CLI) of Abaqus before doing any operation after opening the Abaqus.